# Limit amount of content creation per anonymous user

Tags: 7, users, nodes

In my site anonymous users has access to create one type of content and all data the site stores is user IP address.

How do I limit lets say e.g. 2 nodes creations per IP in 12 hours? And when limit is reached, they get some message instead of creating another node until 12 hour range pass?

Because now some of anonymous users are just abusing and spamming the node creation which is unlimited by default.

UPDATE: I tried using Node Limit, but it doesn't really work. When I load a page with the form which has the limit set, it doesn't load the page and that's a home-page of the site and form is displayed as Form Block via Panels. So instead of a home-page I get redirected to node/add/ and page not found.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could do it custom with [`hook_node_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) and the [Flood API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/flood_is_allowed/7).

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access
 */
function MY_MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

    // Get node type, can be string or node object
    $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
    if ($type == 'type_of_interest') {
      // Check flood limit for anon users node creation
      if ($op == 'create' && user_is_anonymous()) {
        // Ensure checked only once per page request, node/add path only
        $access_checked = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
        if(empty($access_checked) && arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add') {
          // Record the access check for drupal_static
          $access_checked = TRUE;
          // Check create_node limit of 2 per 12 hours
          // Note, you could make the threshold and window config variables.
          if(!flood_is_allowed('create_node', 2, 43200)){
            drupal_set_message(t('There is a node creation limit of 2 nodes per 12 hours. Please try again later.'), 'error');
            return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
          }else{
            // Register the node create event to test against for 48 hours
            // Note, you could move this somewhere else to ensure the node is actually saved, e.g hook_node_insert
            flood_register_event('create_node', 172800);
          }
        }
      }
    }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;

}
```

Comment: This. A thousand times this.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, but I do not understand that 48 hours part.

Comment: So on first try for a new unique never used IP it creates a node, but also prints the drupal_set_message. Also it hides the form, so no chance to create 2nd node within 12 hours. So looks like it almost work, since I'm no PHP guru, I got no idea what needs changing in the code.

Comment: @OptimusPrime it looks like you may have something else calling node_access as well on your install so it's called twice. The solution would be to add some code to ensure it's only checked once per page load (see updated answer) or alternatively, you may need to check the menu path to ensure it's run once on the target path only.

Comment: I think this code blocks entirely all anonymous for 2 nodes per 12 hours, in original question I meant 2 nodes per IP. I exceeded limit with one IP now, and with another I get the limit message.

Comment: @OptimusPrime No, the flood control is per-IP address by default. Check the `$identifier` param in [`flood_register_event`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/flood_register_event/7) docs for more info. Also, to see what's been stored, look at the `flood` table in the database. You may already have an event registered for that IP.

Comment: I checked the flood table. When new IP submits a node, it creates two identical entries in the flood table so that's why it and creates the node and prints the limit message even though only one node was created and one is left to be created, but it already created two entries in the database, so user cannot submit another. This all is too complicating for a non-programmer.

Comment: @OptimusPrime the drupal_static call should prevent that, but perhaps an ajax request or similar is also calling node_access. You could fix that by checking the path in the access check, e.g `if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add'){ ... }` May need to tinker. See my updated answer for an example that checks the node/add path

Comment: What if path is frontpage? The form is exposed in frontpage via Form Block and Panels modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Node Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) module

> The Node Limit module allows administrators to restrict the number of
>   nodes of a specific type that roles or users may create.
>
> - Per-role node limits
> - Per-user node limits

Comment: Hmm, will that really work with anonymous users and per IP?

Comment: Sure it will work for any user role, I have not checked for IP!